# Easily throttle a promise returning method

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I have some code that returns SomeObject as a promise.  It's causing out of memory because I'm triggering it like crazy to do all kinds of work, which would not be an issue if I didn't need its result, but I do.

What I'm really getting at here is - is there a way to inject a throttler into existing code that expects a response, to slow it down depending on machine memory?

The condition it would check is current machine memory level - and only return true if the memory drops below say 85%.  Is there a way to fix this function such that it blocks until the memory is ok?

```
public async throttleThis(config: string) : Promise<ReturnThis> {

await waitUntil()
    .interval(500)
    .times(Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY)
    .condition(function() {
        return (true ? true : false);  // pretend memory is always ok for now
    })
    .done(async function(result: boolean) {
        if(result)
            return await this.doTheOldWork(config);
        else
            return Promise.reject("");    
    });

    // how can I avoid hitting this line and enforce the above chaining to occur
    // so that only SomeObject is returned when memory is ok?
    return Promise.reject("Unfortunately this code is reached right away");
}
```

Comment: returning something from the callback function doesn't makes it a return value of the outer function. In  your case, `throttleThis` function will always return `Promise.reject(...)`

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking this question - is there a way to fix it such that it gives me what I want?

Comment: Can you show us the actual problem code, not your attempt at fixing it?  We could likely make much better suggestions for how to solve the original problem.

Comment: I have workarounds that I can handle, but I'm specifically interested in this.  It sounds like what I want isn't possible - to take an existing piece of code and stick a wedge in it that slows it down, but still returns a response.  The design of my existing system launches flows of work - it would be nice to avoid chunking myself and let a memory throttler do it for me.  I guess there's no way to convert a method like this?

Comment: I guess if it's not possible, I should not require a response as the redesign.

Comment: Possibly relavant: https://github.com/lloyd/node-memwatch